# Open an external file in python

Tags: python

```
x = open('Homework','r')
print(x.name)
x.close()
```

I got this error when I run the code.

```
File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/pythonhome/tobechanged.py", line 16, in <module>
x = open('Homework','r')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Homework'
```

SO I tried to type the full path

```
x = open('C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\pythonhome','r')
print(x.name)
x.close()
```

I got an Unicode error.

btw I'm using windows.

Comment: How do you run the script? That can make a huge difference on path.  
**EDIT:** Also, u didn't type the extension of it. `Homework.txt` or something.

Comment: please what is the full path of the file you have to read?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned, it's usually good to type out the full path to the file, because running a script in IDLE, for example, can cause Python to search for the file in a directory that you are not intending. The reason you got the Unicode error is because you are using a special character, the backslash (`\`) which starts something known as an escape sequence. Escape sequences allow coders to specify special characters, like the newline character: `\n`. You can read more about these in Python's docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

You have to either use a raw string (a string preceded with r, like this `r'C:\Users\...'`), or escape these characters with double backslashes, like this: `C:\\Users\\...`.

Additionally, you need to specify the extension for the `Homework` file, otherwise the file system won't be able to find the file you are referring to, resulting in the `FileNotFoundError` you encountered. As @tdelaney mentioned, these extensions may be hidden by default in Windows Explorer.

Also, the recommended way in Python to open files is using the `with` statement, as this handles closing the object for you. Here is a sample (assuming that the extension of the Homework file is .txt):

```
with open('C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\pythonhome\\Homework.txt', 'r') as x:
    print(x.name)
```

Comment: Full paths are not generally best practice. They limit the placement of data to a single directory. Its useful for your own private scripts - and I think that's your intent here - but I'd shy away from "best practice".

Comment: @tdelaney Good point, but I say best practice because running the same script in IDLE, for example, can cause Python to search for the file in the directory in which IDLE is located, rather than where the script is located. A full path would prevent this unintended consequence

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are forgetting the extension to the file (the ending of it). For example, if you have a text file that is named Homework, you would include it in like this

```
open(r'Homework.txt','r')
```

For this example, it must be in the same directory as your script. If you wanted to open a file outside of your scripts directory, you would have to find the full path of it. Here is an example of the Homework.txt file in my downloads folder.

```
open(r'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Homework.txt','r')
```

You can also see in this code I use an r infront of the path. This tells Python the expression is a raw string and escape sequences are not parsed.

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's issue of the Unicode error, which is created by using the special character `\`. You either need to escape these characters, or use a raw string

Comment: @awarrier99 - but it can explain the problem in the first script. I think that this answer should mention that by default Windows doesn't show file extensions in its GUI but they are needed on the command line. Also, highlight that "txt" is guess... it could be a .docx or any number of other extensions depending on tool used.